# Stop Netbeans IDE form opening class tree in projects tree view

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

i want Netbeans 7.4 to stop automatically showing me classes (library .class files) in project tree (but not my .java files) when i go into the file.

For example:
When i open my App.java file, then Netbeans shows me it in projects tree view. //OK
When i open source file from external lib, then Netbeans shows me it in projects tree view.//NOT OK

Is there any place to configure that behavior??

Comment: Anyone has a solution?